# Why setTimeout in vue.js have this strange behavior?

Tags: vue.js, settimeout, vuejs2

I stated to work with vue.js recently and I don't understand why this behavior happens, using the setTimeout(). With the following code, the function defined in setInterval(function(), time) is launched immediately no matter the value of 'time':

```
timerOn(){

  ...

  this.avatar.timer.data = setTimeout( this.timerFunction(), 10000);
},
timerFunction(){
  ...

  console.log('Hello!!');
  clearTimeout(this.avatar.timer.data);
  this.timerOn();
},
```

But if I use the following code all works fine and the function inside setInterval occurs after the 'time' defined:

```
timerOn(){

  ...

  var This = this;
  this.avatar.timer.data = setTimeout(function() { This.timerFunction()}, 10000);
},
timerFunction(){
  ...

  console.log('Hello!!');
  clearTimeout(this.avatar.timer.data);
  this.timerOn();
},
```

Someone can guide me and say why the first method fails?

Thank you.

Comment: In the first did you mean to say, `this.timerFunction` instead of `this.timerFunction()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This executes `timerFunction` immediately and passes the result as the callback to `setTimeout`.

```
setTimeout( this.timerFunction(), 10000)
```

But, you want to pass a callback to `setTimeout` and `timerFunction` does not return a function. I expect what you wanted was

```
setTimeout( this.timerFunction, 10000)
```

This passes a reference to the function, `timerFunction` to `setTimeout`. The first example, passes the **result** of `timerFunction()` to `setTimeout`.